# as3 hittestobject will activate without running parameters

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright the problem is that I'm trying to make a sphere disappear only when it is touching my crosshair, the problem is that the sphere will disappear whether the crosshair is touching it or not.

My symbols are:

crosshair with an instance of crosshair on the stage

target with an instance of targetBlue on the stage

```
Mouse.hide();
crossHair.startDrag(true);



stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _onStageMouseDown);

function _onStageMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
if (crossHair.hitTestObject(targetBlue), true)
{
    targetBlue.visible = false;
    trace("the mouse is in the target");
} else if (crossHair.hitTestObject(targetBlue), false){
    trace("the mouse is not in the target");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your If-Statement is kinda weird.
Try it like this:

```
if (crossHair.hitTestObject(targetBlue) == true) {
    targetBlue.visible = false;
    trace("the mouse is in the target");
} else {
    trace("the mouse is not in the target");
}
```

Btw, since you're probably making some sort of shooting game, I suggest you check out the `hitTestPoint()` function, which will be much more suitable for this.

Comment: there is just a code snippet in adobe, I managed to use that. However I figured the problem out. I changed the mouse event from stage to symbol

Comment: The problem is that the mouse can't seem to interact with layers adjacent and below it.